# What was the screen that appeared of Senjougahara during her phone conversation with Kaiki?

Tags: monogatari-series

In episode 24 of Monogatari Series Second Season, while Kaiki is on the phone with Senjougahara, an image of her outside his window appears. During their conversation there are several other similar images.

What is this image supposed to represent?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to note is that this is a clear reference to [Blade Runner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner), the American scifi classic movie. In fact, it's the same reference as was made in Uchouten Kazoku (see [Is the "wakakusa" ad a references to something?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/is-the-wakakusa-ad-a-references-to-something/4736#4736)), namely to the famous [geisha ads in Blade Runner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ17UsZ0DEQ) which play several times throughout the movie. These ads are for the gastrointestinal drug ["Strong Wakamoto"](http://www.wakamoto-pharm.co.jp/english/product/index.html), which is a real product that is quite popular in Japan, but essentially only known in the West through its connection to Blade Runner. It's not unusual that this scene would get referenced many times in different works, since it's one of the most memorable scenes in the movie and plays several times.

Here, the visible text from the OP above is 「．．．力わかも．．．」, which could easily be completed to 「強力わかもと」("*kyouryoku wakamoto*") which is exactly what the original Blade Runner ads said and also the name of the product. There's also the iconic pill swallowing animation a little bit later, which again is a very strong reference to the original ad:

[Click for large animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZku.gif)

As for why exactly the ad plays here, it's impossible to be sure, but there are several possible reasons. Of course, Monogatari tends to throw lots of references out just to keep viewers on their toes, and this is probably one of them. On a deeper level, it could be used in much the same way as the original ad, to disorient and slightly confuse viewers. Of course, given that the geisha is supposed to be attractive, a third possibility is that this is a metaphor to show that Kaiki has some attraction towards Senjougahara (there are some other hints of this as well in Koimonogatari).